# Error: Cannot resolve module 'realm'

Tags: react-native, realm

I'm using the latest version of react-native "0.50.3". I installed realm via npm "npm install realm --save" and linked it "react-native link". But when I tried to import it on my project it shows and error "Cannot resolve module 'realm'"

Comment: We are in the process of updating to RN 0.50.x (due to changes in Xcode 9): https://github.com/realm/realm-js/pull/1483. Feel free to contribute any observations (like the above).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to link library manually. Can you tell me that in your xcode project do you have RealmReact.xcodeproj ?

Comment: Yes. I tried linking it manually, but still the same. By the way I'm using android.

Answer (score 0):

It also happens to me. And i tried the older version  realm 2.28.1 and it solved the problem